# Ejecutar una funcion de javascript dentro de un archivo typescript

Tags: typescript, configuración

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, actualmente tengo un proyecto que tiene algunos archivos en typescript y otros en javascript-

mi estructura de carpetas es la siguiente
Para todo lo que es javascript, files .js

```
js/src
```

Para todo lo que es typescript, files .ts

```
js/typescript
```

Tambien tengo configurado mi proyecto para que todo lo que esta como typescript se comppile dentro de una carpeta

```
js/bin/compiled
```

Por ahora tengo dos archivos
siteController.ts

```
class SiteController {
    eventManager:any;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.eventManager = new EventManager(this);
    }
}
```

y 
test.js

```
var test = function()
{
    console.log("se ejecuto test");
}
var siteCOntroller = new SiteController("test");
```

Ahora bien, mi problema es el siguiente
Si desde test.js instancio siteController funciona todo bien, sin tirar ningun error

Si desde siteController.ts llamo a la funcion test();
la cual esta definida como se ve dentro del archivo test.js

El compilador me tira el siguiente error:

```
js/typescript/siteController.ts(6,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'test'.
```

No termino de entender donde esta el problema, a modo de ejemplo y si sirve deje aqui mi codigo:

```
staging.mdiconcept.com/intercambio/dev_test_typescript_deploy.rar
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer llamadas a funciones JavaScript en ficheros externos. Simplemente necesitas declarar la función para que typescript se entere de que existen.

Bien como variable de tipo anónimo:

```
declare var test;
```

o de tipo interfaz:

```
interface __test { }
declare var test: __test;
```

También puedes incluir esto en un fichero de declaraciones pero no es obligatorio.