# Activar funcion Javascript desde Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy actualmente en un componente TS haciendo validaciones, sin embargo tengo un evento en un archivo javascript que llamé de la siguiente manera:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'assets/js/ruleta.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Este es mi script ruleta.js

```
 var indicator = new TimelineMax();
    var spinWheel = new TimelineMax();
    indicator.to(active, .13, { rotation: -10, transformOrigin: "65% 36%", ease: Power1.easeOut })
        .to(active, .13, { rotation: 3, ease: Power4.easeOut })
        .add("end");

    //  Luckywheel animation
    spinWheel.to(wheel, 5, {
        rotation: deg, transformOrigin: "50% 50%", ease: Power4.easeOut, onUpdate: (
            function () {
                //_gsTransform: current position of the wheel
                tolerance = currentRotation - lastRotation;

                if (Math.round(currentRotation) % (360 / 12) <= tolerance) {
                    if (indicator.progress() > .2 || indicator.progress() === 0) {
                        indicator.play(0);
                    }
                }

            }
        )
    });
    spinWheel.add("end");
```

Básicamente estoy tratando de llamar a una animación que hace girar una ruleta de la fortuna, el caso es que me gustaria **desde Typescript llamar a la función de Javascript, para que la animación se ejecute**

```
girarRueda(){
  activarRuleta(360);
}
```

**Algo similar. ¿Hay alguna forma de llamar dicha función desde TS?**

ADD:

Intenté esto

```
 girarRueda2(){
   this.script.activarRuleta();
}
```

Debido a que previamente declaré un script.src en el ngOnInit, pero sigue sin dar resultados

Comment: puede que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67818/ejecutar-una-funcion-de-javascript-dentro-de-un-archivo-typescript) te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logré resolver así:

- Para definir una función que está en mi archivo Javascript, en Typescript, usando el mismo nombre coloqué:

  ```
  declare var activarRuleta:any;
  ```

Luego importas el javascript con el AppenChield:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    this.script = document.createElement('script');
    this.script.src = 'assets/js/ruleta.js';
    head.appendChild(this.script);
  }
```

Y por consiguiente, podrás utilizar la función en cualquier lugar del archivo TS, simplemente invocándolo:

```
 activarRuleta();
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tengamos el siguiente Javascript **ruleta.js**:

```
function girarRuleta(){
    console.log("Girando")
}
```

Puedes usarlo desde TypeScript de la siguiente manera:

```
girarRueda(){
    window["girarRuleta"]();
}
```

Debería funcionar perfectamente, saludos.

Comment: Esto no funciona, me indica  "El elemento tiene un tipo 'any' implícito porque la expresión de índice no es de tipo 'number'.ts(7015)"

Comment: Lo siento, me he equivocado, colócalo así:  window["girarRuleta"]();

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que hace la propiedad window[], podrías explicarme un poco sobre ello? te lo agradecería mucho. La verdad es que no está activando la función

Comment: Si claro, Window apunta al propio objeto ventana es decir hace referencia a la página web o ventana que está abierta, incluyendo todas las funciones o variables que esten declaradas, Por lo que le estas diciendo a TypeScript en la ventana hay una función llamada girarRuleta y quieres ejecutarla, procura ejecutarla solo si el archivo javascript esta añadido por ejemplo: 
`let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(window["girarRuleta"] == null){
        return;
      }
      clearInterval(interval);
      this.girarRueda();
    }, 1000)
`

Eso es si quieres que se ejecute solo.

Comment: Si el archivo Javascript no se ha añadido aún antes de llamar `window["girarRuleta"]();` no funcionará, Por eso te puse ese ejemplo que puedes colocar en el `ngOnInit` si quieres que se ejecute automáticamente, sino puedes simplemente colocar un botón en la interfaz que llame a esa función, depende de lo que estés desarrollando.